# reverse relation question in Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, relations

I have a reviews section with an entry field to Commerce products. I'm trying to show the reverse relationship review on the product page. It appears to work when there are related entries but when there are no related entries it appears to show random results. How can I show related reviews and no others?

```
{% set relatedReviews = craft.entries({
    section:        'reviews',
    orderBy:         'postDate desc',
    relatedTo:       product
}) %}

{% if relatedReviews %}
{% for relate in relatedReviews %}
   ...
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't get random entries when no related entries were found. Relation queries add a `where` condition that limits what entries can be returned – if no related entries exist, the query will return nothing.

The most likely explanation is that the reviews are related to the products through some other field. In this case, you can limit the `relatedTo` query further by using the [hash syntax](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/relations.html#the-relatedto-parameter) to only include results where the product is the `targetElement`, and also limit the query to a specific field:

```twig
{% set relatedReviews = craft.entries({
    section: 'reviews',
    orderBy: 'postDate DESC',
    relatedTo: {
        targetElement: product,
        field: 'related_product',
    }
}) %}
```

Replace `related_product` with the handle of the field on the reviews section where the product is selected.

For a multi-site, you can also limit the query further by `sourceSite`.